# Possibly uninitialised variable from conditional

Tags: rust

I'm writing a program that subsets an incoming file into either one or two output files depending on a CLI flag.

Minimally it works like so:

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::Write};
fn main() {
    // Would be a CLI flag
    let write_all = true;

    let mut evens = File::create("evens.txt").expect("Nuh-uh");
    let mut odds: File;
    if write_all {
        odds = File::create("odds.txt").expect("Nuh-uh");
    }

    for i in 1..5 {
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            write!(&mut evens, "{}\n", i).expect("Can't write");
        } else {
            if write_all {
                write!(&mut odds, "{}\n", i).expect("Can't write");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This won't compile due to `odds` being potentially uninitialised/out of scope as it's created in a conditional.

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `odds`
  --> src/main.rs:17:24
   |
17 |                 write!(&mut odds, "{}\n", i).expect("Can't write");
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `odds`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59435780/3279716) about using `Option<File>`, but cannot see how to apply it to my problem.

Another alternative I've considered is just creating the `odds.txt` file and removing it at the end if `!write_all` is true, but I don't like this solution.

Comment: Not an answer to your issue, just a side-comment: it's true that `odds` is initialised in a conditional, but the conditional is (should) known to be always true at compile time. I guess the compiler wasn't very clever here.

Comment: _"but cannot see how to apply it to my problem."_ That would be the culprit. The book has a section on [how the enum `Option` works](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html?highlight=Option#the-option-enum-and-its-advantages-over-null-values), if you are still confused about that. Could you show an attempt at using it?

Comment: @cornuz the language has strict semantics, the dead code doesn't really enter *that* equation. Not to mention OP clearly notes that `write_all` is only a constant local for the sake of demonstration.

Comment: Instead of having odds as a File, have it as an Option<File>, and instead of checking write_all all the time, check if the Option is Some(file).

Comment: @E_net4thejanitor Thank you for the pointer, I think I get it now. If you get a chance could you take a look at my answer?

Comment: @JPMoresmau I think that's what I've done in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Option<File>` you need to set `Some(File)` or `None`. Then to use `File` you need to unwrap the `&mut Option<File>` to `Option<&mut File>`, which can be done using [`as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut) or by matching `odds`.

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::Write};
fn main() {
    // Would be a CLI flag
    let write_all = true;

    let mut evens = File::create("evens.txt").expect("Nuh-uh");
    let mut odds: Option<File>;
    if write_all {
        odds = Some(File::create("odds.txt").expect("Nuh-uh"));
    } else {
        odds = None;
    }

    for i in 1..5 {
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            write!(&mut evens, "{}\n", i).expect("Can't write");
        } else {
            if write_all {
                // let mut file = odds.as_mut().unwrap();
                // write!(&mut file, "{}\n", i).expect("Can't write");
                match odds {
                    Some(ref mut file) => write!(file, "{}\n", i).expect("Can't write"),
                    None => panic!("No file?"),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would replace the `if write_all / match odds` with a single `if Some(file) = &mut file { ...`

Comment: Also the first `write_all` conditional could be `let mut odds = write_all.then(|| File.create(...));`

Comment: Here's a complete version using strings in lieu of files: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=121b3715de3cfb86f5bcb22cc9cded50